# kotlin startactivity with flags

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to start an acitvity through Anko context using kotlin, But would like to use flags

```
 override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MyActivity>) = with (ui) {
        verticalLayout {
            // load something
            button ("Back") {
                onClick {
                    // goes back to the previous activity
                    startActivity<PreviousActivity>()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am raising an activity like so,

```
startActivity<PreviousActivity>()
```

How can I add the flags to reorder the activity to top

This did not work, get a type mismatch error

```
startActivity(intentFor<PreviousActivity>("id" to 5).singleTop())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using so,

```
getContext().startActivity(intentFor<PreviousActivity>().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Intents

I think `singleTop()` is what you're looking for

```
startActivity(intentFor<SomeOtherActivity>("id" to 5).singleTop())
```

Comment: Required Pair < String, Any> found Intent ... that is the error

Answer (score 0):

**I use the following code to start an activity with FLAGS**

```
val intent = Intent(this@home_paciente,LoginActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

The part of

> this@home_paciente

is the context of the activity so you put **this@activity_name** or replace with **applicationContext** and

> LoginActivity::class.java

is the new activity to launch